# Show that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^n\bigl|k\bigl(f\bigl(\frac{1}{k}\bigr)-f\bigl(-\frac{1}{k}\bigr)\bigr)-2f'(0)\bigr|$ exists

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, derivatives

Suppose $f\in C^3[-1,1]$, show that

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^n\left|k\left(f\left(\frac{1}{k}\right)-f\left(-\frac{1}{k}\right)\right)-2f'(0)\right|$$

exists.

I realized that

$$\lim_{k\to\infty}k\left(f\left(\frac{1}{k}\right)-f\left(-\frac{1}{k}\right)\right)-2f'(0)=0$$

by the definition of derivative. I didn't really see how to use the condition $f\in C^3[-1,1]$. Does anybody have any hints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have using Taylor expansion:

$$f\left(\frac1k\right)=f(0)+\frac1kf'(0)+\frac1{2k^2}f''(0)+O\left(\frac1{k^3}\right)$$
and similarly
$$f\left(-\frac1k\right)=f(0)-\frac1kf'(0)+\frac1{2k^2}f''(0)+O\left(\frac1{k^3}\right)$$
hence we get
$$f\left(\frac1k\right)-f\left(-\frac1k\right)=\frac2kf'(0)+O\left(\frac1{k^3}\right)$$
so the given sum is

$$\sum_{k=1}^n\left|O\left(\frac1{k^2}\right)\right|\le M\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac1{k^2}=\frac{M\pi^2}{2}$$
so the given sequence is increasing and bounded above so convergent.

Comment: Very easy and elegant...Thank you.

Comment: You're welcome.

Answer (score 0):

From $f\in C^3[-1,1]$ it follows that $f(x)=f(0)+xf'(0)+x^2f''(0)/2+O(x^3)$ as $x\to0$. Now
$$\frac{f(1/n)-f(-1/n)}{1/n}-2f'(0)=\frac{f(1/n)-f(0)-1/nf'(0)}{1/n}+\frac{f(-1/n)-f(0)-(-1/n)f'(0)}{-1/n}\\=1/n\,f''(0)/2+O(1/n^2)-1/n\,f''(0)+O(1/n^2)=O(1/n^2)$$
So it's easy to see the sum converges as $\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac1{n^2}$ is convergent.